# ICommand with navigation

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, winrt-xaml, icommand

I'm working on a WinRT app and I'm trying to use a command for a button.

```
public class addCommand : ICommand
{
    private async Task AddNewVehicle()
    {
        vvm VM = new vvm();
        await VM.AddNewVehicleInfo();
    }

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return true;
}

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    AddNewVehicle();

}
```

}

After the AddNewVehicle() method is called and completed I want to move to my details page.  In the click event I had something like this:

```
 this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(VehicleItemDetailPage), 0);
```

However, when I add that to my command I'm getting error that it doesn't know what `Frame` is.

How do I navigate to my detail page after the command has been executed?

**Updated XAML Code:**

```
<Button x:Name="addButton" Style="{StaticResource AddAppBarButtonStyle}" Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Frame}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass Frame field as `Execute` parameter. E.g.

```
<Button Command="{Binding CommandName,CommandParameter={Binding ElementName=Frame}}"/>
```

After that you just cast `parameter` to `Frame` and use it as you wish.

Comment: for winRT it looks to have a little different syntax.  I added a CommandParameter like this: Command="{Binding AddCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Frame}"   However, when I stepped into the command code the parameter was still null.

Comment: @JeffV: ElementName expects an x:Name attribute value.  Thus "Name".  Some UIElement in your visual tree has a Frame property.  Name it, then reference it from your binding.

Comment: @Will I added an x:Name="addButton" on my button element and I'm getting the same result.  Is that what you were referring to?

Answer (score 3):

I would just call

> ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(VehicleItemDetailPage), 0);

instead of `this.Frame` and the Thing with passing any Parameters from the XAML which you do not need. Because the Frame is static. So you do not need the Instance of the current initiated View in Code.